Is there a verb that expresses the idea of being influenced by an influencer to the extent of wanting to buy the promoted item?
Like in the title, I'm just wondering if there is a verb could be used to describe this situation? This verb was recently created in Mandarin, I'm just curious if a similar verb has been created in English.

And what is this verb in Mandarin? Could you give an example sentence perhaps? Even if it is in Chinese it would help us understand.

"Influence" might work. Or "brain-washed", "manipulated", "easily led". We need more information, e.g. is it slang or MBA-English? Negative or positive?

As the answers posted so far indicate, there are quite a few general terms that can be used for that purpose. Are you looking for a term that is specific to the contexts in which influencer would be used? If so, you may wish to make that more explicit in the question.

We've had one for a long time.
They sold me on (something) or I was sold on (something).

sold on - uncritically attached to or enthusiastic about
Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Some dictionaries list it as slang, but informal would be my take on it. Collins lists "convinced of" as a synonym,  which softens the "uncritically" bit.

sold (someone) on; selling (someone) on; sells (someone) on. : to persuade (someone) to be interested in and excited about (something)
He tried to sell them on the project. often used as (be) sold on. She wasn't sold on the idea.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sell%20%28someone%29%20on.



I was persuaded by an influencer to buy it. / An influencer persuaded me to buy it.

persuade (v.)

In passive. To be or become convinced, assured, or certain that something is the case, or of something.
[OED online]


To make someone do or believe something by giving them a good reason
to do it or by talking to that person and making them believe it
There would be absolutely nothing healthy about them, but you would be persuaded by pictures and ads to eat them.
From Los Angeles
Times
Cambridge


If you persuade someone that something is true, you say things that
eventually make them believe that it is true.
I've persuaded Mrs Tennant that it's time she retired.
Collins



Although a celebrity can drive sales, an influencer can persuade
their followers to engage with a brand and may have a more long-term
benefit for the brand (Nazeral, 2018).
Alison Theaker; The Public
Relations Handbook (2020)


Related, the term influence is often used interchangeably with
persuasion. Originating from Latin, the word influere meant influx or an inflow, and later, in Shakespearean times, the word
referred more specifically to a cosmic force affecting one's destiny
(Scott, 2019). While we may not ponder our cosmic destiny in the same
way as did Romeo and Juliet, think of how we use the word "star" to
mean someone with exceptional talent or a prominence in a way that
affects others. Likewise, today's term "influencer" includes
someone who has the ability, through digital connectivity, to promote
products, behaviors, and even ideologies. In this way, influence is
related to persuasion; while persuasion is a strategic action,
we hold that influence is the capacity to affect others, albeit
indirectly.
Marianne Dainton and ‎Elaine Zelley; Applying
Communication Theory for Professional Life (2022)


By using the principles of influence and  persuasion you will have
power over people whether your intentions are good or not. The reason
for this is because the principles work for good reasons and for bad.
Franciele Souza; Influencer Secrets (2021)


Social media platforms can be used to persuade individuals to
adopt particular beliefs or behaviors. Persuasive techniques used
on social media can include emotional appeals, personal stories, and
the use of influencers to endorse products or ideas (Ki & Kim,
2019)
Nesma Emam Soliman; Persuasion Arts and Artificial
Intelligence Applications (2024)

